# Modifing data inside list of dictionary

Tags: python

I've a `data = [{"message" : "Hello", "message" : "" }]` and i would like to to change that empty string into `"IMG"`. 
I've tried this function:

```
def clean_empty_string(dict):
    for i in range(len(dict)):
        for key, value in dict[i].items():
            if key == 'message' and value == '':
                dict[value] = "IMG"
    return dict
```

But I'm getting error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.
Is there any easier way to clean that data?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you have a `list` of `dict`s, not a single `dict`? Your parameter name is *very* misleading in that case. Also, your `dict` literal cannot exist once constructed; the same key can't be repeated twice.

Comment: You shouldn’t use dict as a parameter, it is the dict, not some random parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem in your code is that you sent a list of dictionaries and treated it as a dictionary

another problem was that you has two keys with the same name in your dictionaty
so i fixed bouth

```
data = [{"message2" : "Hello", "message" : "" }]

def clean_empty_string(lst):
    for dict in lst:
        for key,value in dict.items():
            if key == 'message' and value == '':
                dict[key] = "IMG"
    return lst

print(clean_empty_string(data))
```

output:

```
[{'message2': 'Hello', 'message': 'IMG'}]
```

but a better solution overall is:

```
def clean_empty_string(lst):
    for dict in lst:
        if 'message' in dict and dict['message'] == '':
            dict['message'] = "IMG"
    return lst
```

since you shouldn't loop over the dictionary keys to find the one you want, you can just check if its already in the dictionary and if it is change it

print(clean_empty_string(data))

hope I could help
if you didn't understand anything feel free to ask me in the comments

if my comment helped you, marking it as the answer or upvoting will go a long way :)

Comment: They shouldn't have the loop over `dict.items()` at all; enumerating all the keys to find the one you want is silly.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionnary cannot have two keys with equal name.
Assuming you have a dict as follows:

```
data = {"message" : ""}
```

Then you can use the following function:

```
def clean_empty_string(dict, word_substitute):
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if key == 'message' and value == '':
            dict[key] = word_substitute
    return dict
```

So that:

```
clean_empty_string(data, 'IMG')
```

returns what you need

Answer (score 0):

You want to access element in a dictionnary by their key, not their value.
Also, in your function `dict` refers to the list of dictionnary, so you would need to change the value like this
`dict[i][key] = "IMG"`.

Your dictionary also have the same key twice which can't happen. You need to change one key in your dictionary.

Also, avoid using `dict` as a variable cause it shadows the built-in `dict` method. You could use `lst` for example.

So the whole code could be

```
data = [{"message": "Hello", "message2": ""}]


def clean_empty_string(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for key, value in lst[i].items():
            if key == 'message2' and value == '':
                lst[i][key] = "IMG"
    return lst

print(clean_empty_string(data))
```